# C# - Get-NetFirewallRule is not recognized when invoking powerShell.AddCommand

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-firewall

I'm using Powershell to query a few networkrelated things and want to alter existing firewall rules accordingly.

I've added a static PowershellHandler-class to my programm which is basicaly just sending a script and returning the rusult as a string.

```
private static string Command(string powerShellScript)
{
    string errorMsg = string.Empty;

    powerShell.AddScript(powerShellScript);

    // make sure return values are outputted
    powerShell.AddCommand("Out-String");

    PSDataCollection<PSObject> outputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
    powerShell.Streams.Error.DataAdded += (object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        errorMsg = ((PSDataCollection<ErrorRecord>)sender)[e.Index].ToString();
    };

    IAsyncResult result = powerShell.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outputCollection);

    // wait for powershell command/powerShellScript to finish executing
    powerShell.EndInvoke(result);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var outputItem in outputCollection)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(outputItem.BaseObject.ToString());
    }

    // clears the commands we added to the powershell runspace so it's empty the next time we use it
    powerShell.Commands.Clear();

    // if an error is encountered, return it
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMsg))
        return errorMsg;

    return sb.ToString().Trim();
}
```

This working fine with `Resolve-DNSName`

```
powerShellResult = PowerShellHandler.Command("Resolve-DNSName -Name " + fullyQualifiedDomainName + " -Server " + DnsServer + " | Select-Object IPAddress");
List<string> powerShellResultList = powerShellResult.Split("\r\n").ToList();
```

or `Invoke-WebRequest`

```
powerShellResult = PowerShellHandler.Command("(Invoke-WebRequest -uri \"" + uri + "\").Content");
List<string> powerShellResultList = powerShellResult.Split("\r\n").ToList();
```

But when I try to use `Get-NetFirewallRule` the same way I'm getting the following error

```
powerShellResult = PowerShellHandler.Command("Get-NetFirewallRule -Enabled true | Select-Object Name, DisplayName");
```

powerShellResult ends up being

```
"The term 'Get-NetFirewallRule' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."
```

When I run this in Powershell directly I get the expected result, so it should work

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Apache Reverse Proxy"

Name                          : {FADD5C1C-67E7-4261-BFA8-DFB6F0665ED4}
DisplayName                   : Apache Reverse Proxy
Description                   :
DisplayGroup                  :
Group                         :
Enabled                       : True
Profile                       : Any
Platform                      : {}
Direction                     : Inbound
Action                        : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy           : Block
LooseSourceMapping            : False
LocalOnlyMapping              : False
Owner                         :
PrimaryStatus                 : OK
Status                        : Die Regel wurde erfolgreich vom Speicher aus analysiert. (65536)
EnforcementStatus             : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource             : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType         : Local
RemoteDynamicKeywordAddresses : {}
PolicyAppId                   :
```

I've tested the version used by C#

$PSVersionTable returns the same data as the Shell used to get the data above, so it basically runs the same shell

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.6
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.6
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

The error message stays the same running the script in user-mode or as admin, or using Powershell.AddCommand/Powershell.AddStatement.

Any hints, what might cause this? I am flat out of ideas.

Comment: Check Environmental Variable PSModulePath.  The cmdlet will only get recognized if it is in the same folder as the PS script or is on the PSModulePath.  Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath"));  where is cmdlet located?  Search machine.

Comment: The symptom is curious, because the relevant module is a Windows PowerShell system module that even SDK projects should see, because the system-module directory is part of the persistently defined `$env:PSModulePath` environment variable. What happens if you first try to explicitly import the `NetSecurity` module in your project?